# ¿mi código PHP es correcto y/o optimo?

Tags: php, mysql, php7, pdo

Desde un formulario PHP estoy enviando datos y recibiéndolos en otra página PHP para poder validar estos datos e ingresarlos finalmente en MySQL, el Código que realice funciona de manera correcta, pero mi duda es si es el más correcto y/o optimo, dado que también estoy trabajando con imágenes. Lo que hago es validar la imagen y subirla a su directorio correspondiente para así en la base de datos solo guardar la ruta de donde se encuentra la imagen. Quería saber si el lugar donde estoy realizando el ingreso de los datos a MySQL es el correcto, o debería realizarlo justo debajo de cuando realizo la subida de la imagen a su directorio (debajo de move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $archivo)). También me gustaría saber si estoy mostrando de forma correcta los mensajes de éxito y errores en la pagina con las validaciones que realice.

Adjunto el Código PHP:

```
<?php

//Array donde se van a ir guardando los errores
$errors = []; 

if(isset($_POST["btnIngresar"])){

    $producto = $_POST["txtProducto"]; 
    $precio = $_POST["txtPrecio"]; 
    $stock = $_POST["txtStock"];
    $descripcion = $_POST["txtDescripcion"];  

    if(!empty($producto) && !empty($producto) && !empty($producto) && !empty($producto) && $_FILES["txtImagen"]["name"] != null){

        //Validamos el tipo de imagen que vamos a aceptar
        $tipos = array("image/jpeg","image/png"); 
        if(in_array($_FILES["txtImagen"]["type"],$tipos)){

            $carpeta = "img/";
            
            if(!file_exists($carpeta)){
                mkdir($carpeta); 
            }

            $tipo = $_FILES["txtImagen"]["type"];
            $fecha = date("Ymd-His");
            if($tipo == "image/jpeg"){
                $archivo = $carpeta.$fecha.".jpg"; 
            }else{
                $archivo = $carpeta.$fecha.".png";
            }

            if(!file_exists($archivo)){

                $tmpName = $_FILES["txtImagen"]["tmp_name"];
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $archivo)); 

            }else{
                $error[] = "EL ARCHIVO NO EXISTE"; 
            }     
        }else{
            $error[] = "ERROR, TIPO DE IMAGEN NO COMPATIBLE";
        }

        //Una vez ya subida la imagen al arvicho, insertamos los datos hacia la base de datos 
        require("conexion.php"); 
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO producto (nombre, precio, stock, imagen, descripcion) VALUES (:nombre, :precio, :stock, :imagen, :descripcion)"); 
        $stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $producto); 
        $stmt->bindParam(":precio", $precio); 
        $stmt->bindParam(":stock", $stock); 
        $stmt->bindParam(":imagen", $archivo); 
        $stmt->bindParam(":descripcion", $descripcion); 
        $resultado = $stmt->execute(); 
        $db=null; 

    }else{
        $error[] = "ERROR, DEBE LLENAR TODOS LOS DATOS"; 
    }

}else{
    $error[] = "ERROR AL INGRESAR PRODUCTO"; 
} ?>
```

Adjunto HTML que se encuentra en el mismo archivo PHP, que muestra las mensajes de error o de éxito si se insertaron correctamente los datos:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ingreso</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-ingreso">
        <?php
        
            if(isset($resultado)){
                if($resultado){
                    echo "<h3 class='title-ingreso success'>PRODUCTO INGRESADO CORRECTAMENTE</h3>"; 
                }else{
                    $error[] = "ERROR"; 
                }
            }

            //Si existen errores en el array, imprimimos esos errores 
            if(count($error)>0){
                foreach($error as $i){
                    echo "<h3 class='title-ingreso error'>".$i."</h3>"; 
                }
            }

        ?>
        <a href="formulario-ingreso.php" class="btn otro-ingreso">INGRESAR OTRO PRODUCTO</a>
        <a href="index.php" class="btn ver-producto">VER PRODUCTOS</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Deberías verificar lo que ocurrió con `move_uploaded_file()` antes de hacer la inserción, ya que actualmente, si hay algún error guardando el archivo, ocurrirá una inserción, pero tal archivo no existirá realmente. Queda pendiente la seguridad con respecto a los archivos que estás subiendo, controlar extensiones, mime tpye, etc. Revisa por ejemplo [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38509334/5587982) y sus respuestas.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si, eso estuve analizando, hacer una condicional que si el move_uploaded_file() me devuelve true, ahí recién debajo insertar los datos hacia la base de datos verdad??

Comment: Exactamente....